# wpf Grid column add summary of column

Tags: c#, wpf, list, devexpress

I have a grid that has a list of items. One of the items in the list is a price. 
Say you have 5 items in this list, I need the total of the price but it needs to be displayed in the list as well.

```
<dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Row" ItemsSource="{Binding Temp}" dependencyProperties:BestFitColumn.IsEnabled="True" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedTemp}">
<dxg:GridControl.Columns>
      <dxg:GridColumn Header="{x:Static meta:MetaCommon.Price}" FieldName="PriceDisplay"/>
</dxg:GridControl.Columns>
```

I trimmed down the code down due to its size.
Would the best method be to create an item in the list that contained the summary price or is there a way to add the summary into a footer?

Comment: How do you set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid?

Answer (score 1):

```
<dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary> 
    <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="Price" SummaryType="Sum"/> 
</dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
```

This should be what you are looking for.
More information here:
https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6128